# Enable brotli compression for apache-tomcat-9.0.5

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx, brotli

I want to enable brotli compression for on my apache-tomcat-9.0.5. I want to implement the same for JS/CSS/HTML content. Most of the users coming to my site use chrome. Is this feasible? Is there any documentation which i can refer? Is it possible without additional layer of Apache and Nginx server

Answer (score 1):

Been looking for the same answer as well and it seems support for brotli is lacking.
Official documentation for compression doesnt mention brotli at all.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

However seems like there is a way with some Java bindings...heavent tested it though!

https://twitter.com/nitram509/status/677643202460065792